# Either of the girls is capable or Either of the girls are capable?

Tags: grammaticality

I got a question in a practice test that went along like this:
Which sentence is correctly expressed?

A. Either of the girls is capable of taking the prize.
B. Either of the girls are capable of taking the prize.
C. Neither of the girls are capable of taking the prize.
D. None of the above.

The answer to the question was A. Could someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 0):

In formal English (which is what you will see on standardized tests), the words *either* and *neither* are considered to be singular. In this example, "of the girls" is a prepositional phrase that modifies the pronoun *either*, but *girls* (which is the object of the preposition *of*) doesn't affect subject-verb agreement here. The subject is *either*, which is singular, so the correct verb choice is *is*, which agrees with a singular subject.

This concept also comes up in sentences featuring a singular subject modified by a prepositional phrase that has a plural object of the preposition. (For example, "The purpose of these tests is to...," "A group of students was traveling...," or "A box of cookies was sitting on the table.") Let me explain this in a little more detail using the following example: "**A box of cookies was sitting on the table.**"

In order to understand the grammatical structure of this example sentence, let's first consider the simpler sentence, "**A box was sitting on the table.**" In this simpler sentence, the subject is *box*, which is singular, and therefore the correct verb would be *was* (which agrees with a singular subject) and not *were*.

Now, let's add a little more detail to the sentence by describing what kind of "box" we are talking about.  We can say, "A box **of cookies** was sitting on the table." By adding the prepositional phrase "of cookies," we are giving more information about what kind of box it was, but it is still a singular *box* (not the plural form, *boxes*). The number of boxes we are talking about is "**a box**," meaning "**one box**," meaning that it's singular. Therefore, it would be correct to write/say, "A box of cookies **was** sitting on the table," where the verb *was* agrees with the singular subject *box*. The fact that *cookies* is plural does not affect subject-verb agreement since it's part of the prepositional phrase that is merely modifying the subject *box*.

In this sense, you can think of the prepositional phrase "of cookies" as **similar to an adjective** that's telling us what kind of "box" this is.  A "box" could (in theory) be many different kinds of boxes: It could be "a **big** box," "a **green** box," "a **cardboard** box," "a box **of bananas**," "a box **with a bow on top**," "a box **that my aunt sent me**," "a **dusty old** box **full of Christmas ornaments**," etc. However, in the example I gave, it happened to be "a box of cookies." In each of these examples, though, we are talking about a singular "box," regardless of what happens to be inside of the box or what type of box it is.

The same concept applies to words such as *each* and *(every) one* when they are used in this way.  For example, it would be formally correct to write/say, "*Each* of the students **is** giving a presentation today" or "*One* of the plane's engines **has** failed, but the other three engines are fully operational."

However, in **casual speech**, you will nearly always hear *either* and *neither* treated as plurals in cases such as this one.  For example, in casual speech, you will often hear (or see) things like "Are either of you coming?" or "Neither of them are here yet." Just keep in mind that this is considered informal (and incorrect) for the purposes of standardized tests or academic writing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it made a lot more sense, especially with the example of the "box of cookies" as it made it substantially more simple for me to understand.

Comment: Did you make an AI produce that very long answer?

Answer (score 0):

In formal writing and speech, **either** [one] **of** {you / us / them} takes the singular verb

1. Either [**one**] of the girls [them] **is** capable of taking the prize.

When the compound subject is joined by *or* such as *either…or…* and the subject is singular, the verb is singular too.

2. **Either** Asia **or** Kim **is** capable of taking first prize.
3. **Either** Asia **or** Kim **has done** enough to win first prize.
4. **Does** either Asia **or** Kim like skiing?

When the compound subject is joined by *and*; a plural verb is normally required

- **Do** Asia **and** Kim need new skis? YES
- **Do** Asia **and** Kim needs new skis? NO

When the compound subject is joined by *or* and each subject is singular, the verb is singular too.

5. But if either [**one**] of them **wins** first prize, I'll be pleased.
6. Either Asia or Kim **is** going to win.

But if the compound subject is plural then the verb must also be plural

7. Either the girls or boys **are** going to take the prize. (*boys* is plural, so the verb is also plural)

In brief,  it is never wrong to use the singular verb with the constructions **either of** and  **either X or Y** when the subject is singular (1-6) especially in formal language and in English language tests.

The *American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language* includes the following notes on usage:

> When all the elements in an *either … or* construction (or *a neither  nor* construction) used as the subject of a sentence are singular, the verb is singular:
>
> - *Either Eve or Herb **has been** invited*.
>   Analogously, when all the elements in the *either … or* construction are plural, the verb is plural too:
> - *Either the Clarks or the Kays **have been** invited.*